# Power Form Docusign

Tags: api, docusignapi, e-signature

I am fetching the powerForm url to send contracts to clients. I would like to know if there is a way to get the envelopeId created once I fetch that url.

This is everything i got from the call [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr0JK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

PowerForms are for end-users, not for your integration.

If what you want is what you describe, you don't need a powerform, just a template and then you use the API to make an envelope from the template that you send to your recipients.

Follow code example in here:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/